# inter process comunication by mailbox python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, ipc

I want to realize a communication program between 10 process by mailbox. The number of boxes letters is limited to 5. Each process can send and / or receive messages from any other process but if all mailboxes are busy, the request of the sender must be placed in a queue. The role of message manager (identification of the author and recipient, transfer of the message and release of the mailbox) is assigned to a 'supervisor' thread that explores regularly the mailboxes, regardless of functioning of worker threads (which produce the messages). How should I start?
I tried this but I don't know if it's what I am looking for.

```
class srvthread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialisation d’un thread
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) 
        self.socket.listen(5) 
        self.setDaemon(True) 
        self.start()
```

**sendMessage.py**

```
import socket
def sendSocketMessage(message):
    # Send a message to a socket
    try:
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) 
        client.send(message)
        client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        client.close()
    except Exception, msg:
        print msg

if __name__ == "__main__":
sendSocketMessage("message")
```

Comment: @J Doe please define your code here, that you have try

Comment: @JignashaRoyala I edited my post

Comment: @JignashaRoyala so what do you think? what should I do next?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is Message Passing Architecture. It's possible to implement message passing for IPC with sockets, but this is likely too low level for most applications to be productive. For simple message passing IPC, you can use multiprocessing.Queue module from the standard library. For something more complex, you may want to consider libraries like MPI or some form of MQ (message queue) like RabbitMQ or Kafka.

Comment: I find your requirements confusing. Why a limit of 5 messages when at the same time you allow for enqueuing? That is a contradiction. Also is there a reason you can’t use multiprocessing with a star topology to gather and forward messages between processes?